# Using variables from global stylesheet to local stylesheet angular scss

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I am using scss with angular, and I want to declare some colors as variables in the general style sheet to access them, but I have no idea how to call them, because I receive the next error

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
   ╷
80 │     background-color: var($green-color);
```

This is my styles.scss

```
$green-color: rgb(42, 132, 83);
```

And I just call it in the other scss file

```
.add {
    background-color: var($green-color);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you setup your sass compilation, but the notation `var(--my-var)` works for css global variables. For sass variables, you just need to import the scss file where you declare variables:

`import 'variables';`

and then call theme directly like:

`color: $my-var;`

Answer (score 1):

I don't generally recommend using variables in scss in your case, give the classic css variables a try

alternatively you can hold the variables in a separate file and then import it where ever you like and THEN use it.